# Click on D3 map circle to create pie chart in popup

Tags: javascript, d3.js, popup, pie-chart

i m new to D3 and am working on a map recently. I have these codes to generate circle markers on the map and it works fine, here are my questions:

1. Is it possible when user click on the marker, the popover can show some information about that point with D3 pie charts, like the workforce combination etc?
2. what should i do to display the nested workforce combination data in a table form within the popover

this is what i have to create circles and popover:

```
d3.json("data/data1.json", function(collection) {
    // Add a LatLng object to each item in the dataset
    collection.objects.forEach(function(d) {
        d.LatLng = new L.LatLng(d.circle.coordinates[0],
                                d.circle.coordinates[1])
    })

    var feature = g.selectAll("circle")
        .data(collection.objects)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .style("stroke", "#e8e8e8")  
        .style("opacity", .25) 
        .style("fill", "#614855")
        .attr("r", function(d){return Math.sqrt(d.workforce)*20;})
        .on("click", (function(d,i){
        console.log(this,$(this))
        $(this).popover({
         'title': 'Title',
        'content': popupContent(d),
        'trigger' : 'click',
        'placement': 'top'
        }).popover("show")
        })
        );

        function popupContent(d){
        var html = "<b>Workforce: </b>" + d.workforce + "<br/><b>LatLng: </b>" + d.circle.coordinates[0] + "," + d.circle.coordinates[1] + "<br/><!--How can i loop the combination of workforce here? or to show the pie chart here?--></div>";
        return html;
    }
```

And a sample json like this:

```
{"objects":[
{"circle":{"coordinates":[-35.03833,117.619724]},"workforce": 71587, "combination":[{"work":"bluecollar","size":28645},{"work:":"whitecollar","size":30442},{"work":"others","size":12500}]}]
```